# Storybook asks me to choose if my project is using Vite or Webpack 5, but I am using Rollup

Tags: webpack, vite, storybook, rollup

I am trying to build my first component library. Following a guide, I've simply initiatd a new empty npm project added rollup as the builder and started adding all my components in the src directory (in the components folder).

When trying to ad Storybook, it says: `We were not able to detect the right builder for your project. Please select one:` and lets me choose between Vite or Webpack 5, but it's neither. What should I do? Should one of them work better than the other? Would they both cause issues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vite is using rollup for production build, so its preferred to choose Vite

ref: [https://ruslan.rocks/posts/vite-vs-rollup#:~:text=Vite%20uses%20Rollup%20for%20production,to%20create%20production-ready%20bundles](https://ruslan.rocks/posts/vite-vs-rollup#:%7E:text=Vite%20uses%20Rollup%20for%20production,to%20create%20production-ready%20bundles).

Comment: Good to know! I thought they are both doing the same thing just differently. Thank you